# Can't restore Skype window

Tags: unity, skype

on 13.10, my skype seem to be properly installed, I have the skype icon in the task bar and it starts automlatically after boot. I normally go into the taskbar icon to open my contact window. This works fine.... at first...
But after a while this last bit doesn't work and there is no way I can restore my contact window (or do anything else in skype). The taskbar icon and menu is still there and is opening fine but none of the menu items are working.
I eventually have to kill the process and start skype again to fix that.

Any idea why that stops working ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the indicator applet appears to now be treating left-clicks to skype as the action to bring up the menu, instead of restoring the main window. I think it's an issue with the panel or indicator applet and not skype, since I didn't change the version of skype I have installed when upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10.